# How to check the return value of a function pointer in dlsym?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am writing a library which will load dynamic library using dlopen and invoke the function given.

My function pointer expect a function pointer which have return type as int.

```
typedef int (*function_handle)(int);
```

Return type of one function is void in the shared object.

```
 void some_function_ret_void(int b)
```

But dlsym not throws any error if i assign this pointer to fn.

```
typedef int (*function_handle)(int);
function_handle fn;
```

Is there a way to check the return value of a function pointer got from dlsym ?

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*function_handle)(int);
int main()
{
  void* handle=dlopen("./libtest.so",RTLD_LAZY);
  function_handle fn;
  int retval =0;
  char *err;
  /**** How to check the return type of fn *********/

  fn=dlsym(handle, "some_function_ret_void");
  if ((err = dlerror()) != NULL) {
    printf("Could not invoke the handler %s",err);
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
  }

  /* 
    if(fn return type is void don't print anything)

    if(fn return type is char* , print the charecter) 
         free(str);
  */

  retval = fn(4);
  printf("%d",retval);  
  dlclose(handle);
  return 0;
}
```

## in libtest.c (libtest.so)

```
int some_function_ret_int( int a) {
     return a+10;
}

char* some_function_ret_str(int b) {
 //allocate memory for string and return;
}

void some_function_ret_void(int b) {
 //allocate memory for string and return;
}
```

Comment: It's only the compiler that compiles the current translation unit that keeps track of return types. Once compiled, there is no information about the argument or return types. Using the wrong return type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The same goes for the parameters. There's no way to tell what parameters a function is expecting. C doesn't define any reflection data.

Comment: `dlsym` will just return the address (as a `void *`) where the function (or other shared object) has been loaded in memory. It's up to your code to convert the returned `void *` to the desired type. In some ways, your problem is similar to that of declaring an external function with an incorrect prototype. It will compile and link, but will produce _undefined behavior_ when you call it at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to check the return value of `dlsym()`.

There is no return value intelligence in `dlsym()` - `dlsym()` doesn't even know if your symbol is a function pointer or a data pointer. You should probably look at other ways of implementing your design than depending on the return value / type of `dlsym()`.

> The dlsym() function shall search for the named symbol in all objects loaded automatically as a result of loading the object referenced by handle.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html

Answer (score 1):

The underlying question -- how to implement plugins that provide different types of functionality -- is very interesting.

For example, consider a simple [Reverse Polish calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), with a plugin interface that adds new operators.

Instead of having the main program use `dlsym()` to find each symbol, have the plugins export just one -- say, `plugin_init()` -- that takes a registration function as a function pointer parameter. Each plugin then calls the registration function once per every feature it wishes to add.

An RPN calculator is based on a stack. If we assume that every operator can resize the stack, the operator function prototype is basically

```
int operation(double **stackptr, int *countptr, int *maxcountptr);
```

where `*stackptr` is a pointer to the current stack, `*countptr` is the number of `double`s in the stack, and `*maxcountptr` tells the size allocated (in `double`s) for the stack. If the operation is performed successfully, it'll return `0`, otherwise a nonzero `errno` error code.

Consider this **application.c**:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct operator {
    struct operator *next;
    int            (*func)(double **, int *, int *);
    char             name[];
};

struct operator *operators = NULL;

static int register_operator(const char *name,
                             int       (*func)(double **, int *, int *))
{
    const size_t     namelen = (name) ? strlen(name) : 0;
    struct operator *curr;

    /* Make sure name and func are valid. */
    if (!namelen || !func)
        return EINVAL;

    /* See if name is already used. */
    for (curr = operators; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        if (!strcmp(name, curr->name))
            return EEXIST;

    /* Allocate memory for this operator. */
    curr = malloc(namelen + 1 + sizeof (struct operator));
    if (!curr)
        return ENOMEM;

    /* Copy function pointer and name. */
    curr->func = func;
    memcpy(curr->name, name, namelen + 1); /* Include terminating '\0'. */

    /* Prepend to list. */
    curr->next = operators;
    operators = curr;

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}

static int list_operators(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    struct operator *curr;

    fprintf(stderr, "Known operators:\n");
    for (curr = operators; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        fprintf(stderr, "\t'%s'\n", curr->name);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double *stack = NULL;
    int     count = 0;
    int     maxcount = 0;
    int     arg;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s ./plugin ... NUMBER [ OPERATOR | NUMBER ] ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (register_operator("list", list_operators)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to register built-in 'list' operator.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        struct operator *op;
        double           val;
        char             dummy;

        /* Check if argument is a plugin path, starting with "./". */
        if (argv[arg][0] == '.' && argv[arg][1] == '/') {
            void  *handle = dlopen(argv[arg], RTLD_NOW);
            if (handle) {
                int (*func)(int (*)(const char *, int (*)(double **, int *, int *))) = dlsym(handle, "plugin_init");
                if (func) {
                    int failure = func(register_operator);
                    if (failure) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Operator registration failed: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(failure));
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }
                } else
                    dlclose(handle);
                continue;
            }
        }

        /* Check if argument is a known operator. */
        for (op = operators; op != NULL; op = op->next)
            if (!strcmp(op->name, argv[arg]))
                break;
        if (op) {
            int failure = op->func(&stack, &count, &maxcount);
            if (failure) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot apply operator: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(failure));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            continue;
        }

        /* Parse as a number. */
        if (sscanf(argv[arg], " %lf %c", &val, &dummy) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unknown operator.\n", argv[arg]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* Make sure stack has enough room for an additional number. */
        if (count >= maxcount) {
            double *temp;

            maxcount = (count | 255) + 257;
            temp = realloc(stack, maxcount * sizeof *stack);
            if (!temp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(ENOMEM));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            stack = temp;
        }

        /* Push val to top of stack. */
        stack[count++] = val;
    }

    for (arg = 0; arg < count; arg++)
        printf("[%d] = %g\n", arg + 1, stack[arg]);

    return (count == 1) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The `struct operator *operators` is a global singly linked list of known operators. The `register_operator()` function prepends new operators to the list, unless the name is already taken.

The only built-in operator is `list`, so you can list the known operators.

Let's see a couple of different plug-in implementations. First, **plugin_basic.c**:

```
#include <errno.h>

static int op_add(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    if (*count < 2)
        return EINVAL;

    (*stack)[*count - 2] = (*stack)[*count - 1] + (*stack)[*count - 2];
    (*count)--;

    return 0;
}

static int op_sub(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    if (*count < 2)
        return EINVAL;

    (*stack)[*count - 2] = (*stack)[*count - 1] - (*stack)[*count - 2];
    (*count)--;

    return 0;
}

static int op_mul(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    if (*count < 2)
        return EINVAL;

    (*stack)[*count - 2] = (*stack)[*count - 1] * (*stack)[*count - 2];
    (*count)--;

    return 0;
}

static int op_div(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    if (*count < 2)
        return EINVAL;

    (*stack)[*count - 2] = (*stack)[*count - 1] / (*stack)[*count - 2];
    (*count)--;

    return 0;
}

int plugin_init(int (*register_operator)(const char *name,
                                         int       (*func)(double **, int *, int *)))
{
    int  failure;

    if ((failure = register_operator("+", op_add)))
        return failure;

    if ((failure = register_operator("-", op_sub)))
        return failure;

    if ((failure = register_operator("x", op_mul)))
        return failure;

    if ((failure = register_operator("/", op_div)))
        return failure;

    return 0;
}
```

which provides the four basic operators `+`, `-`, `x`, and `/`; and **plugin_sincos.c**:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int op_sin(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    if (*count < 1)
        return EINVAL;

    (*stack)[*count - 1] = sin((*stack)[*count - 1]);

    return 0;
}

static int op_cos(double **stack, int *count, int *maxcount)
{
    if (*count < 1)
        return EINVAL;

    (*stack)[*count - 1] = sin((*stack)[*count - 1]);

    return 0;
}


int plugin_init(int (*register_operator)(const char *name,
                                         int       (*func)(double **, int *, int *)))
{
    int  failure;

    if ((failure = register_operator("sin", op_sin)))
        return failure;

    if ((failure = register_operator("cos", op_cos)))
        return failure;

    return 0;
}
```

which provides `sin` and `cos` functions.

Because only the `plugin_init()` function needs to be exported dynamically, let's add a common symbol file, **plugin.syms**:

```
{
    plugin_init;
};
```

Note that I have explicitly marked many functions `static`. This is to avoid namespace pollution: to ensure that they are not visible to other compilation units, which might otherwise cause conflicts. (Although the symbol file should ensure only the `plugin_init()` is dynamically exported, the `static` reminds me as a programmer which functions are not supposed to be exported in any case.)

Finally, a **Makefile** to bind it all together:

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O2
LD      := $(CC)
LDFLAGS := -lm -ldl

.PHONY: clean all

all: rpcalc basic.plugin sincos.plugin

clean:
        rm -f rpcalc basic.plugin sincos.plugin

rpcalc: application.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

basic.plugin: plugin_basic.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared $^ $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-dynamic-list,plugin.syms -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@

sincos.plugin: plugin_sincos.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared $^ $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-dynamic-list,plugin.syms -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@
```

Note that the intended lines must start with a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, not eight spaces. If you're unsure, run `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` to fix.

Compile the calculator and its plugins:

```
make clean all
```

If you run

```
./rpcalc list
```

it will tell you that the only supported operator is `list` itself. However, if you run e.g.

```
./rpcalc ./basic.plugin list
./rpcalc ./*.plugin list
```

it will show the operators implemented by the plugins.

It is a working calculator, too. If you wanted to calculate, say, `sin(0.785398) x cos(0.785398)`, run

```
./rpcalc ./*.plugin 0.785398 sin 0.785398 cos x
```

and the program will output `[1] = 0.5`, as you'd expect.